# I do not know if I used too much 'yield return new WaitForSeconds' in the coroutine function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

** Unity5.6.5f1 / C#

I used a coroutine to run the animation.

Rather than creating multiple if statements in the update function,

I thought coroutine would be better.

But I think I used 'yield return new WaitForSeconds' too much,

Is it common to write coroutines this way?

```
private IEnumerator AnimationControl()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(41f);        
    objAni.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    obj2Ani.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    obj3Ani.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    objAni.Play("Stay");
    obj2Ani.Play("Stay");
    obj3Ani.Play("Stay");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.667f);        
    objAni.Play("Run");
    obj2Ani.Play("Run");
    obj3Ani.Play("Action");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.666f);
    objAni.Play("Fire01");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.334f);
    obj3Ani.Play("Panic");
    obj2Ani.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(8.333f);
    objAni.Play("Fire02");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(6.333f);      
    objAni.Play("Fire03");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(6.1337f);       
    obj3Ani.Play("Stay");
    objAni.Play("Stay");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.2003f);        
    obj3Ani.Play("Surprise02");
    objAni.Play("Surprise");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.333f);                
    obj3Ani.Play("Run");
    objAni.Play("Run");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(6f);
    objAni.Play("Stay");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.667f);      
    objAni.Play("Run");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.333f);        
    obj3Ani.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.667f);        
    objAni.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.333f);
    textObj.SetActive(false);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.667f);
    endingObj.SetActive(true);
    allObj.SetActive(false);
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: That looks like a disaster waiting to happen. You should look into how to do proper animation in Unity.

Comment: It would be good to mention and show the code you are running after each wait. I think that will determine if there is a better way to do this

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do a cutscene. The coroutine may work, but the right way to do this would be using Animators and Timelines.

Comment: I added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what coroutine is used for, which is to execute many code sequentially and even wait anytime. It's not really too much. The only issue I see is creating new `WaitForSeconds` every time. If you know the time to wait or you hard-coded the times, declare the `WaitForSeconds` outside the function then yield against them. This really depends on how often you call the `AnimationControl` function.

For example,

```
private IEnumerator AnimationControl()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(41f);
    objAni.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    obj2Ani.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    obj3Ani.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    objAni.Play("Stay");
    obj2Ani.Play("Stay");
    obj3Ani.Play("Stay");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.667f);
    objAni.Play("Run");
    obj2Ani.Play("Run");
    obj3Ani.Play("Action");
}
```

becomes

```
WaitForSeconds wTime1 = new WaitForSeconds(41f);
WaitForSeconds wTime2 = new WaitForSeconds(5.667f);

private IEnumerator AnimationControl()
{
    yield return wTime1;
    objAni.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    obj2Ani.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    obj3Ani.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    objAni.Play("Stay");
    obj2Ani.Play("Stay");
    obj3Ani.Play("Stay");

    yield return wTime2;
    objAni.Play("Run");
    obj2Ani.Play("Run");
    obj3Ani.Play("Action");
}
```

---

---

If you really want to reduce the `WaitForSeconds` code, you can make a wrapper class around it. This class should hold the time to wait or even better, `WaitForSeconds` instance then use `Action` to represent the code you want to execute after the wait. Create a `List` of this `class`, loop over it, wait then execute the code in the `Action` variable.

The Wrapper class:

```
public class AnimControlInfo
{
    public WaitForSeconds waitTime;
    public Action action;
}
```

Create a List of it:

```
List<AnimControlInfo> animInfo = new List<AnimControlInfo>();
```

Initialize the `List` so that it can be used in the `AnimationControl` function:

```
void InitControlAnimInfo()
{
    AnimControlInfo aI1 = new AnimControlInfo();
    aI1.waitTime = new WaitForSeconds(41f);
    aI1.action = delegate
    {
        objAni.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        obj2Ani.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        obj3Ani.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        objAni.Play("Stay");
        obj2Ani.Play("Stay");
        obj3Ani.Play("Stay");
    };

    AnimControlInfo aI2 = new AnimControlInfo();
    aI2.waitTime = new WaitForSeconds(5.667f);
    aI2.action = delegate
    {
        objAni.Play("Run");
        obj2Ani.Play("Run");
        obj3Ani.Play("Action");
    };

    //Add to List
    animInfo.Add(aI1);
    animInfo.Add(aI2);
}
```

Then your new `AnimationControl` function to wait and play animation or activate/de-activate GameObects:

```
private IEnumerator AnimationControl()
{
    //Loop over the List, wait then do action
    for (int i = 0; i < animInfo.Count; i++)
    {
        yield return animInfo[i].waitTime;
        if (animInfo[i].action != null)
            animInfo[i].action();
    }
}
```

The amount of code in the `AnimationControl` function has been reduced. It also reduced the excessive use of the `WaitForSeconds` class.